# How to change Laravel-Nova action name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Actually, I need to change the laravel nova action name like translate into different languages.

```php
class PrintWithDetail extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        $id = '';
        //
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $id = $model->id;
        }
        return Action::openInNewTab(route("print.work.order", [$id, 'type' => 'detail']));
    }

}
```

Above action show **PrintWithDetail** as name.

But, I need to change **PrintWithDetail** into dutch.

Answer (score 10):

Override the public property `$name`

```php
/**
 * The displayable name of the action.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $name;
```

So in your example

```php
class PrintWithDetail extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name = "Print met detail";

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        $id = '';

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $id = $model->id;
        }
        return Action::openInNewTab(route("print.work.order", [$id, 'type' => 'detail']));
    }
}
```

You can see all what you can change in the class the action extends in `nova/src/Actions/Action.php`

#### Update

If you need the name localized in other languages, you may override the method `name` return a string from the Laravel [`__()`](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-__) helper method

```php
/**
 * Get the displayable name of the action.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function name()
{
    return __('Print with details');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. By the way, I also did it as same like you mentioned above.

Comment: @Saly can you tell me , how to change default prefix "Create/Update" that comes with CRUD?

Comment: How do we fetch relationships for names? like if it is a pivot table...

Comment: This works but it will also use the name as key for the action_events logging table making tracking difficult if you use multiple languages at the same time.